# Socket.io will not work

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have changed my files to look as shown below. The javascript console shows nothing and the web page shows nothing. Just a blank screen. Does anybody know of a web site which uses socket.io. I would like to inspect the code to see how they do it since none of the examples on the socket.io page work for me. Does anybody know if extra ports need to be allowed in the iptables file?

Using the Chrome browser, if I goto the javascript console and goto the Network tab I get successes but the last call says Pending ??? It looks like it is hung. Could this be a firewall issue?

```
/socket.io/1/websocket
GET
101
Switching Protocols
Pending
Other
127 B
0 B
Pending
```

it is Pending in selector.js on line 168:

```
document.body.appendChild(menuDiv);
```

Maybe this is why I am not seeing anything? It is properly serving up socket.io/socket.io.js

Files below:

```
//app.js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var port = 80;

var io = require('socket.io').listen(server, {
log : false
});
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
   socket.on('hi', function(data) {
      console.log('yay');
      socket.emit('hello');
   });
});
server.listen(port);
```

public/index.html

```
//index.html
<script src="http://localhost/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
   var chat = io.connect('http://localhost/chat')
   , news = io.connect('http://localhost/news');

   chat.on('connect', function () {
      chat.emit('hi');
   });

   chat.on('hello',function(){
       console.log('yay got hello');
   });

   var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:80');

   socket.on('connect', function () {
      chat.emit('hi');
   });

   socket.on('hello',function(){
       console.log('yay got hello');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using namespaces `news` and `chat` even though your server doesn't implement them correctly.

You javascript connection should look like this instead:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:80');

socket.on('connect', function () {
   chat.emit('hi');
});

socket.on('hello',function(){
    console.log('yay got hello');
});
```